# query issue - query not pulling correctly

Tags: php, mysql, join

So I'm having some issue wrapping my head around a query I should using for a feature I need to implement.

```
TABLE_A
ORDERS_ID  CUSTOMER_ID  CUSTOMER_NAME
11121      78125        David Garcia
11122      78126        Joe Smith
11123      78139        Vincent Lee
11124      78144        Howard Dorf

TABLE_B
ORDERS_ID  PRODUCTS_ID  BACKORDER_DATE
11121      245-A        NULL
11121      781-B        NULL
11121      777-K        NULL
11122      854-J        2014-06-29
11122      245-A        2014-07-05
11122      986-O        2014-07-01
11123      555-P        2014-06-28
11123      777-K        2014-06-28
11124      854-J        2014-07-11
11124      731-T        2014-06-30
```

---

```
SELECT o.BACKORDER_DATE 
FROM TABLE_B o 
JOIN TABLE_A q ON q.ORDERS_ID = o.ORDERS_ID 
WHERE q.CUSTOMERS_ID = $customer_id_var
```

Now everything is being pulled correctly, I'm only running into one issue. If the order has multiple back order dates and they are not the same then it will pull the first one and stop. Now I have no problem with that but if the first back order date is further into the future than the next one, I run into issues.

Take for instance the last two rows in Table_B. The date the query will pick up is 2014-07-11. That is a huge issue because 2014-06-30 will come and go with out any notification. The system will believe that 2014-07-11 is the earliest back order date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean you want to ORDER BY the backorder date?

```
"SELECT o.BACKORDER_DATE 
FROM TABLE_B o 
JOIN TABLE_A q ON q.ORDERS_ID = o.ORDERS_ID 
WHERE q.CUSTOMERS_ID = $customer_id_var 
ORDER BY o.BACKORDER_DATE ASC"
```